# How do I implement a collision response between two non-rotatable rectangles

Tags: java, game-physics

I need help making a top-down shooter game, I don't know how to stop my player from going right through the block, and down below is my Player class and my keyInput class. 
  I'm new to game programming, I have searched a lot of different solutions but don't know how to implement them...
(Sorry if I'm not being very detailed, I just don't really know how to properly explain my code)
*
The Image is what happens when you run the code, I can move the player
[image]

```
package main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class Player extends GameObject{

    Handler handler;


    private int timer = 20;
    private boolean canFire = false;
    public static int direction = 1;
    public Player(int x, int y, ID id , Handler handler) {
        super(x, y, id);
        this.handler = handler;



    }
    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return new Rectangle (x, y, 16, 16);

    }
    public void tick() {
        x += velX;
        y += velY;


        x = Game.clamp(x, 0, Game.WIDTH - 31);
        y = Game.clamp(y, 1, Game.HEIGHT - 54);
        if(timer >= 0) timer --;





        if(KeyInput.facing[0] == "Up") {

            direction = 4;
        } else if(KeyInput.facing[1] == "Down") {

            direction = 3;
        }else if(KeyInput.facing[2] == "Left") {

            direction = 2;
        }else if(KeyInput.facing[3] == "Right") {

            direction = 1;
        }


        if(KeyInput.Fire == true) {
            if(timer <=0)
            {

                handler.addObject(new Bullet(x + 8, y + 8,ID.Bullet, handler, direction));
            timer = 20;
            }

        }


        collision();
    }

    private void collision() {
        for (int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++) {
        GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);

        if(tempObject.getId() == ID.Block)
        {
            if(getBounds().intersects(tempObject.getBounds()))
            {
                //collision events

            }
        }
    }

} 
    public void render(Graphics g) {

        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect((int)x,(int)y,24,24);


}

}
```

```
package main;

import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class KeyInput  extends KeyAdapter{

    private Handler handler;
        private boolean[] keyDown = new boolean[4]; 
        private double Multi = 1;
        public static String[] facing = new String[4];
        public static boolean Fire = false;


    public KeyInput(Handler handler) {
        this.handler = handler;
        keyDown[0] = false;
        keyDown[1] = false;
        keyDown[2] = false;
        keyDown[3] = false;
        facing[0] = "";
        facing[1] = "";
        facing[2] = "";
        facing[3] = "";
        }   
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();

            GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(0);

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_W) {tempObject.setVelY((int)(-3* Multi)); keyDown[0] = true;facing[0] = "Up";}

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_S) {tempObject.setVelY((int)(3* Multi)); keyDown[1] = true;facing[1] = "Down";}

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_A) {tempObject.setVelX((int) (-3* Multi)); keyDown[2] = true;facing[2] = "Left";}

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_D) {tempObject.setVelX((int)(3 * Multi)); keyDown[3] = true;facing[3] = "Right";}

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT) {Multi = 2.2;}

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {Fire = true;}

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) System.exit(0); 
        }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(0);
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_W)  {keyDown[0] = false;facing[0] = "";}//tempObject.setVelY(0); 
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_S) {keyDown[1] = false;facing[1] = "";}//tempObject.setVelY(0);
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_A) {keyDown[2] = false;facing[2] = "";}//tempObject.setVelX(0);
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_D) {keyDown[3] = false; facing[3] = "";}//tempObject.setVelX(0);
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT) {Multi = 1;}
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {Fire = false;}

    if(!keyDown[0] && !keyDown[1]) tempObject.setVelY(0);
    if(!keyDown[2] && !keyDown[3]) tempObject.setVelX(0);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Thats a lot of code and you did not guide us through it. Also, it is hard to really understand your issue without actually running your code. It would help if you provide some pictures or a more detailed description. Voting to close this question because it needs more focus and details.

Comment: It really depends on how you handle the positioning of your character. I couldn't make out how you do that from your code. If you have a `2D-Array` like structure containing objects or stuff like that you can just compare the two positions and then decide if you actually want to move the Character based on the input. Otherwise its probably a good idea to look at `Collision detection` algorithms.
Also, either way you probably want to make an extra function for movement and not directly modify values in `keyPressed()` because that gets messy really quick.

Comment: @DJSchaffner, my xPos += velX, so when I change my velX, my xPos also changes. I'm trying to keep the collision code inside the collision method if I can, because I don't fully understand 2d arrays just yet.  Also I don't understand what you are saying by not directly modifying values in keyPressed()

Comment: If you are only working with non-rotated rectangles you can try [this](http://www.jeffreythompson.org/collision-detection/rect-rect.php). Depending on the shapes and rotations you might have to look for other ways of detecting collision

Comment: @DJSchaffner, My rectangle of a Player doesn't rotate so thanks for the link! I'll be sure to read that in my spare time!

Comment: You don´t need to manually check the collision like it does on the link @DJSchaffner gave you. You already have a collision method that uses a rectangle object that already knows how to check if it intersects with another rectangle. You already have a working collision detection, what you need now is to implement the collision response.

Comment: @Logan, Yes, thats the point, I need a response, which I don't how to implement the response.

Comment: ok, I wrote a response having this into account. Hope it helps

Comment: Oh, sorry then. Looks like I didn't read properly. Thought you needed to check for a collision and not how to deal with the result of a collision

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two strategies you can use for collisions: correction or prevention.

Correction means you move the character and then you check if it collides, and if it does, you apply a correction. Which means, you find the position where the player should be and move it accordingly. This is called "responding to the collision".

Prevention, on the other hand, implies doing some check before moving, and then only move the player as far as the collision point. This would require, for instance, some raycast technique.

In your case, you probably want to implement a "correction" approach, given how your code is organized.

You have a pice of code that checks if a collision occurred (I'll assume it works). When a collision is detected you can call some method to correct the position.

```
private void collision() {
    for (int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++) {
        GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);

        if(tempObject.getId() == ID.Block)
        {
            if(getBounds().intersects(tempObject.getBounds()))
            {
                //collision events

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Theres an interesting question on gamedev stackexchange you can look at for how to implement the collision response: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/160248/2d-rectangle-collision-resolution

I would strongly recommend to use reified vectors instead of plain numbers for the position and velocity. It makes everything easier to understand on the long run.

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to implement it! So, for now, I'll mark this as solved unless I run into an issue!